# Run bash script after login

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a bash script with a series of whiptail menus that allows a user to setup their new system, which is Ubuntu server, with no GUI, just CLI (it's going to be a Virtual Machine image).

I'm already forcing a root login by editing `/etc/default/grub` and `/etc/init/tty1.conf`, so the user is dropped directly into the root command prompt.  From there the user has to type in `./whiptail.sh` to start the script and get the whiptail prompts to further setup their host.

Now, I'd like for my script to be what appears up after the the login occurs instead of the user being dropped to the command prompt.  How can I do this?

Comment: Put the script in `/root/.bashrc`

Comment: Way to easy @heemayl.  Make it the answer!

Comment: don't put it to .bashrc... script will be run each time someone opens a bash session with only this custom .bashrc, won't work for me, because I use zsh.

Comment: @agilob that's a non-issue actually since I'm managing the VM shell.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All interactive sessions of `bash` will read the initialization file `~/.bashrc`.

So you can just add the script at the end of the `root`'s `.bashrc` i.e. `/root/.bashrc`, assuming the script is executable:

```
echo '/path/to/whiptail.sh' >>/root/.bashrc
```

Now the script will be always run when `root` opens a new interactive shell. If you only want to run while login only, not all all interactive sessions you should rather use `~/.bash_profile`/`~/.bash_login`/`~/.profile` (the first one available following the order).

Answer (score 13):

If you want it to be **global**, add you script to

```sh
/etc/profile
```

If you want it to be **user-specific**, add you script to

```sh
/home/$USER/.profile
```

Consider upvoting the original answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56088/343022

Comment: or add the shell script to `/etc/profile.d` for `global`